# Electronic window tinting, darkening

Tags: remote, smart

Does anyone know a DIY project to make window glass dark/tinted electronically? (some kind of DIY foil). The goal is to turn it dark/clear with a remote. You may call it smart window :)
eg:

http://www.smarttint.com

[www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiT9U7R809g](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiT9U7R809g)

Comment: I was thinking 1pixel LCD, but I guess that's not possible @home.

Comment: google switchable LCD privacy glass

Answer (score 1):

The material you need to source is called electrochromic glass. I've never bought it, but perhaps having the correct name will help you find it. It's not something you can make at home most likely.

This kind of material is used in the fairly sizable passenger windows of the Boeing 787 Dreamliner- a bit gimmicky, and I rather prefer the A380 in general, but it's interesting- avoids the necessity of having the sliding shades that the stews have to wake up people to open and close every time you pass a sunrise.

Comment: +1 Maybach, and perhaps some of the larger Mercedes, offer it in their rear windows for privacy, and (if I remember rightly) a tintable roof instead of a traditional sunroof.